# iOS Program Flow After InputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have an unreasonable delay (3 seconds) in my iOS application between the time a user taps a control and when the keyboard is shown.

To reproduce this, I give textfield #1 focus then quickly resign the keyboard with the keyboard resign button and tap textfield #2.

If I tap between the two fields without manually resigning the keyboard I don't see this delay.

I've tried debugging the app to see the program flow but I'm not good enough with the debugger to actually trace anything, I always end up in assembler.

I know that the delay happens after textFieldShouldBeginEditing returns and after inputAccessoryView returns, but before a kUIKeyboardWillShowNotification is fired. My question is, what happens between these steps? What does the program flow look like between the call of inputAccessoryView and the notification for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification?

I believe that if I could just figure out what IOS is executing in this delay I could come up with a work-around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly believe this was an IOS 8 problem. After changing the target to 9.3 this issue seems to have all but disappeared.